SSH Server error 1067 on Win Server 2019 when using internal-sftp subsystem to allow SFTP but disallow SSH
I've been using the internal-sftp subsystem approach since 2021 without problem to allow SFTP but disallow SSH.
My ssh_config file code is:
ForceCommand internal-sftp
Subsystem  sftp   sftp-server.exe -d \%
ChrootDirectory \%

PermitTunnel no
AllowAgentForwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
X11Forwarding no
AllowUsers sftpuser

As others, over the weekend following October 2024 Windows updates, I can't connect to the server via SSH.
On the server, the OpenSSH SSH server won't start and I get a 1067 error.
As recommended, when I delete the \ssh folder, the service can now be restarted successfully but the new ssh folder automatically created has the default ssh_config file code:
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

When I replace this code with the internal-sftp code above I again get a 1067 error.
Wondering what makes this code incompatible with the new updates.

For more root cause detail: https://serverfault.com/a/1166413/20701

I had the same issue with a similar setup. I ran sshd -D -ddd and saw an error that was encountered on Subsystem line in the config file. I had a full path to a folder and it was in quotes. It did not like the quotes for some reason and started right up.
To make sure you have all the info of things I tried beforehand:

I uninstalled the Windows Feature OpenSSH
Downloaded the latest 64bit version from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/v9.8.1.0p1-Preview
Followed these instructions: https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH#install-win32-openssh-test-release

Extract contents of the latest build to C:\Program Files\
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File FixHostFilePermissions.ps1
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File install-sshd.ps1
New-NetFirewallRule -Name sshd -DisplayName 'OpenSSH Server (sshd)' -Enabled True -Direction Inbound -Protocol TCP -Action Allow -LocalPort 22
net start sshd

This is where I ran the above command sshd -D -ddd


Set-Service sshd -StartupType Automatic



Hopefully this helps you or at least gives you more info to put you in the right direction!
